# Calculation with if statement to define value of a field. Syntax error?

Tags: if-statement, formula, conditional-statements, filemaker

In filemaker, If field1 (date field) is filled, I want field2 value to be "a", if field1 is empty, i want field2 value to be b

I tried
In the options for field2, validated by calculation, specify calculation, and this formula:

```
If (IsEmpty(field1),"valueb","valuea")
```

But I get the following error:
`A number, text constant, field name or “(” is expected here.`

Two Questions.

> 1. will this way work?
> 2. is my syntax wrong?

If anyone could point out what could be wrong, I would appreciate it tremendously.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with your formula. Strictly speaking, you should be using a semicolon `;` to separate the arguments instead of a comma `,`-  but that may be depending on your locale, and in any case Filemaker should be smart enough to understand commas as well.

Comment: ok so changing the comma for semicolon worked, thank you so much! Also it's not validation by calculation but Auto-Enter value...

Comment: Why aren't you using a *calculation* field? Auto-enters are suitable if you plan on overriding the value manually. Or need to validate the result. Note also that for simple text labels, you can use conditionally formatted *text* - with no fields.

Comment: Hello, I used _auto-enter_ instead of _calculation field_ as I might want to override the value manually. It was just a way to fill in the field2 by default based on the date on field1, but I want to be able to change the value manually in some cases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue that you're running into is that you're trying to write a value into a field by using the field's **data validation options** rather than it's **auto-enter** options.

The validation calculation will show your user an error message but does nothing to write to the field other than reverting the field to it's pre-user-edited value.

The auto-enter options will allow you to write data to the field. If the two fields are in the same table, the auto-enter calculation for `field2` will fire when you modify `field1`.

That said, let's take a look at what you're trying to accomplish.

**What you want:**
When `field1` is not empty, `field2` should hold the value "a".
When `field1` is empty, `field2` should hold the value "b".

The **auto-enter calculation** for `field2` should be:

```
if ( not IsEmpty( field1 ) ; "b" ; "a" )
```

If the two fields are in different tables it changes things a bit, but it seems like this is what you're going for.

I hope this helps.